# Git Master Branch Ahead of Destroyed Branch

Tags: git, github

I'm receiving a message while on my master branch saying that: Your branch is ahead of 'origin/' by 100 commits. But, I've destroyed that branch both locally and remotely. Anyone know what's going on and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution:

First, destroy the remote branch with:

```
git branch -d -r origin/<remote branch name>
```

Then, fixup with:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```